# Copying metadata from a custom list to a library with SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a custom list that we're using to track people's travel requests, so they put in the reason they are going, like the name of a conference, and their travel dates.

I'd like to copy the name of the conference, start date and end date to a document library for their receipts.  Right now, I'll be getting the administrator to create a document set manually and retype the information, and I'd like to avoid that.  It's Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use designer to create a workflow on the custom list that creates the document set in the library, and sets certain field values on the new item based on the original travel request.

---

Build the workflow with the intention of attaching it to your custom list.  You can set it to either start automatically or manually (or both), whatever fits your needs.  When you are building the workflow, select the action "Create list item".  Once the action is added to your workflow, it will default to "this list", but you can click on "this list" and select another list on the site.  Here you should be able to select the document library where you want to create the document set.  Here you can also click "Add" to add all the fields that you want mapped.  One important field to set here is Content Type ID, so you can make sure you are creating your document set content type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dylan, that's just what I want to do.  I am unclear how to make the workflow go between a list and a library though.

Comment: @SteveMorley, edited my answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible using designer. I would suggest to use the quick view and update the same data with in the browser.

as an alternative you may consider a programmatic solution using powershell via CSOM if the content is huge.